# JCS failed to load properties

Tags: java, caching, jcs

I am using `JCS` for Caching purposes. I have implemented this on my PC where it works fine but on our Tomcat server as well as on my colleagues PC the error `Failed to load properties for name [/cache.ccf]` appears.

The jar file has been installed correctly and the `cache.ccf` file is in the same location as on my PC so I don't understand why it succeeds for me and fails otherwise.

The code I'm using to obtain an instance of the JCS cache is:

```
JCS.setConfigFilename("/cache.ccf");
printOddsCache = JCS.getInstance(PRINTODDSCACHE_REGION_NAME);
```

The cache.ccf file contains the following:

```
jcs.default=
jcs.default.cacheattributes=org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes
jcs.default.cacheattributes.MaxObjects=200001
jcs.default.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName=org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache
jcs.default.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker=true
jcs.default.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds=3600
jcs.default.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds=60
jcs.default.elementattributes=org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes
jcs.default.elementattributes.IsEternal=false
```

*SOLUTION EDIT
I rewrote the cache.ccf from scratch and it seems to be working without any error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue in my project I working on now. Solution from here helped me a lot: [How to change JCS cache.ccf file's path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733681/how-to-change-jcs-cache-ccf-files-path)
I now that configuration class is less convenient than common properties file, but in this case it's the best solution i've found.